# AC motor speed control circuit

Tags: power-electronics, motor-controller, triac, ac-motor

I connected a circuit found on the internet:

[image: AC motor speed control circuit]

Results:
When the AC motor is connected to the closed circuit, it did turn on, but the speed of the motor keeps increasing on its own without turning off, although varying the potentiometer. Note: I tried 2 different motors.

The TRIAC used is BT139 and the DIAC is DB3 & the inductor value is 220 μH.

How can I fix the problem to be able to control the speed of the motor from the potentiometer?

[image: Circuit Built]

Comment: Nooooooooo!  220VAC on a breadboard is asking for trouble.  They aren't made for high current, and they aren't intended for such high voltage - not to mention the ease with which you can zap yourself or cause a short circuit.

Comment: @JRE Thank you for the safety tip man. But how can I solve the problem

Comment: Start by not building it on a breadboard. You need to solder the connections. Breadboard connections are not all that reliable. With a low voltage circuit, you just wiggle parts and connections until it works. With that 220VAC in there, you can't really just wiggle stuff to find a bad connection.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with pictures of the motors, or links to datasheets if you have them.  While you're at it, supply the part numbers of the TRIAC and DIAC, and note any substitutions you made in part values.  It makes a difference if they're induction motors or series-wound "AC/DC" motors; that's the first thing I'll be checking.  There's a good chance that your TRIAC or DIAC were getting hot and changing characteristics, although since this is a 220V circuit there's not an easy and safe way to tell.  If you have a non-contact thermometer, that would be a good thing to check with.